# Disable default use of Accept-Language header in ASP.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.Net Core, I have the following setup per the documentation on establishing the culture in the application:

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
  new CultureInfo("en-CA"),
  new CultureInfo("fr-CA"),
  new CultureInfo("fr"),
  new CultureInfo("en"),
  new CultureInfo("en-US"),
};

var defaultRequestCulture = Configuration["Settings:Culture:DefaultRequestCulture"];

if (defaultRequestCulture == null)
{ 
  defaultRequestCulture = "en-CA";
}

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
  DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(defaultRequestCulture),
  SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
  SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
});
```

I've added the `Settings:Culture:DefaultRequestCulture` to the `appsettings.json` file so it can be configured on a per site installation basis.

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) indicates that the order can be changed, but unfortunately doesn't provide the example on how to do it.

It indicates that these three providers are used by default:

1. QueryStringRequestCultureProvider
2. CookieRequestCultureProvider
3. AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider

I cannot figure out how to disable the third. I want the other ones to remain as is, but for the application to disregard the HTTP header entirely.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just as you'd like remove any item from an `IList<T>`.

```
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = ...,
    SupportedUICultures = ...,
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US")
};

var requestProvider = localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.OfType<AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider>().First();
localizationOptions.RequestCultureProviders.Remove(requestProvider);
```

Or just

```
var localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
{
    SupportedCultures = ...,
    SupportedUICultures = ...,
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
    RequestCultureProviders = new List<IRequestCultureProvider>
    {
        // Order is important, its in which order they will be evaluated
        new QueryStringRequestCultureProvider(),
        new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
    };
};
```

Comment: Thanks! The first approach worked for me provided that the `Startup.cs` had the System.Linq dependency `using System.Linq;`. I preferred the second one for the succinct nature, but the `IRequestCultureProvider` interface was not available and I couldn't track down the dependency for that.

Comment: `IRequestCultureProvider` is part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization` package and is in the namespace of the same name